# How does IE process this URL "action.do?v=credit/CC/Query&para=123456"

Tags: internet-explorer, parameters, hyperlink

I request this URL

`BillOutQryForCCPre.do?_viewReferer=creditcard/CC/adv/BillOutQry&para=101600000846` in IE,

And I can't get the parameter value.

And when I move my mouse cursor to the hyperlink, I see the URL changed to `BillOutQryForCCPre.do?_viewReferer=creditcard/CC/BillOutQry¶=101600000846`.

The charactors `&para` is changed to `¶`, I don't know why.

And Chrome  doesn't have this problem, Firefox too.

When I change the parameter name `para` to `ssss`, I find the hyperlink normal.

Is the word `para` a keyword in IE?

I know I can switch the parameters order to solve this problem, but I really want to know why it's that.

Comment: And this is why URLs in HTML tags must always be HTML-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

*&para;* is the html entity for the paragraph mark you are seeing there. Apparently, Internet Explorer is trying to be clever and thinks you have left the semi-colon off the end, and so it is converting it anyway.

As mneonneo said in the comment above, you need to HTML-encode the & characters in the url, so that the link you are actually outputting  is

```
BillOutQryForCCPre.do?_viewReferer=creditcard/CC/adv/BillOutQry&amp;para=101600000846
```