# Trouble opening a encoded URL with the javascript method window.open() using Internet explorer.

Tags: javascript, url, internet-explorer-11

Trouble opening an encoded URL with the javascript method window.open() using Internet Explorer. I have a Url: 'http://test.aspx?someparam=somevalue&para_new=somevalue'. When opening the URL the new IE tab has replaced the &para_new with a paragraph character instead of being the &para_new parameter (http://test.aspx/?someparam=somevalue¶_new=somevalue). This works fine using Chrome. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change the word  &para to  something else  like &p_new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use window.open('http://test.aspx?someparam=somevalu`&amp;`para_new=somevalue')

Change & to `&amp;`

[Ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907134/how-does-ie-process-this-url-action-dov-credit-cc-querypara-123456)